# dividing the sum in angularjs does not calculate correctly

Tags: angularjs

I have a tiny angular js snippet. I can get the sum to add up fine, but once I add the division, it does not calculate correctly. Any suggestions on how to solve the division of the sum?

```js
function LoginController($scope) {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
     <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name1" value="1">
    Red
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name2" ng-value="2">
    Green
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name3" value="3">
    Blue
  </label><br/>
  

  
    <h1> Sum: {{color.name1--color.name2--color.name3 / 3 }}! </h1>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Division has a higher precedence than addition/subtraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{{(color.name1--color.name2--color.name3) / 3 }}

```js
function LoginController($scope) {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
     <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name1" ng-value="1">
    Red
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name2" ng-value="2">
    Green
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name3" ng-value="3">
    Blue
  </label><br/>
  

  
    <h1> Sum: {{(color.name1--color.name2--color.name3) / 3 }}! </h1>
    
</div>
```

Comment: why did you place them in the scope too?

Comment: Just to quickly get a sample working with your code that showed you (color.name1--color.name2--color.name3) / 3 rather than color.name1--color.name2--color.name3 / 3

Comment: can i send this calculation to its own ng-model?

Comment: looks like i just apply it to the <h1 ng-model="color:score">{{color.name--color.name1}}</h1>